# Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)

Tags: fortran

I'm working in a finite difference method on an irregular grid, this is the important part of the code:

```
 IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-Z)
      REAL*16 IPSI,ICORR,POT(20000),VA(20000),delta1(20000),
     $delta2(20000),R(20000),a,b,d
      COMPLEX Y(20000),TY2(50000),Z(20000),PSI0(20000),RES,DPSI,C,
     $CORR,OPK
 DO I=3,NR-1
    delta1=R(I)-R(I-1)
    delta2=R(I+1)-R(I)
    a=(2/(delta1*(delta1+delta2)))
    b=(-2/(delta1*delta2))
    d=(2/(delta2*(delta1+delta2)))
    TY2(I)=((d*Z(I+1))+(b*Z(I))+(a*Z(I-1)))
 ENDDO
```

When I try to compile I got Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1) for a,b,d and TY2. Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you writte code like this as a new code, I strongly advise you to change your style. It is not 1982. Your index is implicitly double. You are mixing single complex, double and quadruple reals. Total mess.

Comment: I rolled back to your original question on which an existing answer is based. Your new code was completely different. If you change your code based on the answers and still have a problem, you should ask a new question. Before asking a new question, however, make sure you use `IMPLICIT NONE`. It is worthless to go through such a long piece of code your tried to post without `IMPLICIT NONE`. It is **essential**.

Answer (score 3):

```
    a=(2/(delta1*(delta1+delta2)))
    b=(-2/(delta1*delta2))
```

and the following lines are illegal. On the right you have arrays, on the left a scalar.

Maybe you forgot some index like `delta1(I)` or `delta1` should be a scalar. We can't say without knowing more about your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new at programming. I put the rest of the code in the question. You don't know how much I appreciate your feedback. Thanks!

Comment: @Kev_mad Now your code is completely different and my answer doesn't make sense. You changed the declaration part. You shouldn't do that! Read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309245/721644 You also do not report on which line the compiler report the error. Who is supposed to find it in such a big messy code?